# Event Registration - Confirmation Page Not Shown - Returns to Blank Registration Entry page First Time in a session?

Tags: civievent, joomla

Using CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Joomla 3.4.4

Implemented an Event Registration page on the front end site.

After the Event Registration page is completed and Continue button pressed the Confirmation Page does not appear and the system represents the initial blank Registration page.

If the registration details are re-entered the Confirmation Page appears as it should and the rest of the process completes.

Any ideas please?

Ray

Comment: can you confirm that the urls are consistent throughout - ie that you are not jumping from www to without www or http to https or reverse

Comment: Perfect suggestion. Thank you. I hadn't notice that the original url to the registration page was different. Now that I have made it the same it works correctly.

Comment: I will add as an Answer. Pls 'tick' it so that others know it was the solution. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be a situation where you are jumping from www to without www or http to https or reverse. confirm that the urls are consistent throughout your settings eg civicrm.settings.php